# Change property name dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object

I have an object like this

```
var taskText = {
    0: "t1",
    1: "t2",
    2: "t3",
    3: "t4"
}
```

i'm gonna remove the `1` property using `delete` like this

```
delete vm.taskItem[1]
```

now the result is like this

```
{
    0: "t1",
    2: "t3",
    3: "t4"
}
```

My problem is, is there any way i can revert the next property name to the one that deleting and so on. what i need is an object like this

```
{
    0: "t1",
    1: "t3",
    2: "t4"
}
```

Comment: why not use an array and splice?

Comment: as for my req i had to use an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate the sorted keys and assign the value to the decremented key and delete then the last key.

```js
function deleteKey(object, key) {
    var keys = Object.keys(object).sort(function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        });

    keys.forEach(function (k) {
        if (k > key) {
            object[k - 1] = object[k];
        }
    });
    delete object[keys.pop()];
}

var taskText = { 0: "t1", 1: "t2", 2: "t3", 3: "t4" };

deleteKey(taskText, 1);
console.log(taskText);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Underscore.js or Lodash, there is a function 'omit' that will do it.
[click here for documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#omit)

```
var taskText = {
                 'a': "t1",
                 'b': "t2",
                 'c': "t3",
                 'd': "t4"
               }
_.omit(taskText ,'b'); //It will return a new object

=> {'a' : 't1', 'c' : 't3', 'd' : 't4'}  //result
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var taskText = {
    0: "t1",
    1: "t2",
    2: "t3",
    3: "t4"
}

Object.prototype.deleteByKey = function(key) {
var i = 0; 
for(var k in this) {
 if (k != key) {
  this[i] = this[k];
  i++;
 }
}
};

taskText.deleteByKey(1);

console.log(taskText);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its better you use a JavaScript array.

With a JavaScript array, deleting any element will automatically change the index of the other elements without the need for you to do anything. Also, adding an element will take care of this case. Since your keys are plain numbers here, I think array would be a better solution.